# How to load a php or html file in append

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to load a php file as shown below."How can i insert or load php code"

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $("#btn2").click(function() {
        var num_tabs = $("div#tabs ul li").length + 1;
        $("#tabs ul").append("<li><a href='#tabs-" + num_tabs + "'>Ajay#" +
            num_tabs + "</a></li>");
        $("div#tabs").append("<div id='tabs-" + num_tabs + "'>"
            How can i insert or load php code " < /div>").append(aj);
        $("#tabs").tabs("refresh");

    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: use `$("div#tabs").html('HTML_CODES')`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the `num_tabs` value in your PHP file. Here in my example i have passed it using `tab_num` variable.

Get the `tab_num` variable using `$_GET` in your PHP file. Then just `echo` your desired `HTML` in the PHP file and you will get the data in your `data` variable.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $("#btn2").click(function() {
        var num_tabs = $("div#tabs ul li").length + 1;

        $.get("filename.php", {
            tab_num: num_tabs
        }, function(data) {
            $("#tabs ul").append(data);
        });


        $.get("filename.php", {
            tab_num: num_tabs
        }, function(data) {
            $("div#tabs").append(data);
        });


        $("#tabs").tabs("refresh");
    });

});
</script>
```

filename.php

```
echo '<div id="tabs-'.$_GET['tab_num'].'"><div id="aj"></div></div>';
```